# Writing a regex to replace a specific name with another name in a text column

Tags: r, dplyr, text, replace

I have a data set that includes some texts as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  name=c('Chris is nice','ris is nice and ris is old','Risoto is bad','RIS is bad',
         'rising is nice ', 'Prosis is ris and big','Ris is tall','doris is short'))

df %>% select(name)

                        name
1              Chris is nice
2 ris is nice and ric is old
3              Risoto is bad
4                 RIS is bad
5            rising is nice 
6      Prosis is ris and big
7                Ris is tall
8             doris is short
```

I need to replace only `ris` names that have no strings before or after and are shown as `ris`. Such words need to be replaced with `LTD`.

The outcome of interest would be:

```
                        name
1              Chris is nice
2 LTD is nice and LTD is old
3              Risoto is bad
4                 LTD is bad
5            rising is nice 
6      Prosis is LTD and big
7                LTD is tall
8             doris is short
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest `mutate(name = gsub("\\<ris\\>", "LTD", name, ignore.case = TRUE))`

```
library(dplyr)
  
df <- data.frame(
  name=c('Chris is nice','ris is nice and ris is old','Risoto is bad','RIS is bad',
         'rising is nice ', 'Prosis is ris and big','Ris is tall','doris is short'))

df %>% 
  mutate(name = gsub("\\<ris\\>", "LTD", name, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(name)
```

```
                        name
1              Chris is nice
2 LTD is nice and LTD is old
3              Risoto is bad
4                 LTD is bad
5            rising is nice 
6      Prosis is LTD and big
7                LTD is tall
8             doris is short
```

Comment: my apologies, this is actually the whole dataset. I should have shared is completely. I hope you have a solution

Comment: which one do you suggest: ```gsub("^ris ", "LTD ", name, ignore.case = TRUE)``` or ```gsub("\\<ris\\>", "LTD", name, ignore.case = TRUE)```

Comment: when I tried it in ``` ris is nice and ric is old ``` it does not fix the second ``` ris```. It looks like it can't recognize the ``` ris``` in the middle of sentence

Comment: the second one is `riC` not `riS`

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be ```ris``` and I edited it now. But the code can't fix those ones in the middle of sentences. It only captures those that are at the beginning of the sentences.

Comment: `gsub("\\<ris\\>", "LTD", name, ignore.case = TRUE)` will do the job

Comment: Can you please take a look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250599/removing-dates-in-any-format-form-a-text-column-in-r) I posted today? I think you may be able to solve it. Thank you again