# Removing dates ( in any format) form a text column

Tags: r, replace, data-cleaning, stringr

Hope everyone is well.
In my dataset there is column including free texts. My goal is to remove all dates in any format form the text.
this is a snapshot of the data

```
df <- data.frame(
  text=c('tommorow is 2022 11 03',"I married on 2020-01-01",
         'why not going there on 2023/01/14','2023 08 01 will be great'))
df %>% select(text)

                               text
1            tommorow is 2022 11 03
2           I married on 2020-01-01
3 why not going there on 2023/01/14
4          2023 08 01 will be great
```

The outcome should look like

```
               text
1            tommorow is 
2            I married on 
3            why not going there on 
4            will be great
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach would perhaps be to have a sensitive regex pattern:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  text=c('tommorow is 2022 11 03',"I married on 2020-01-01",
         'why not going there on 2023/01/14','2023 08 01 will be great'))

library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(left_text = str_trim(str_remove(text, "\\d{1,4}\\D\\d{1,2}\\D\\d{1,4}")))

#>                                text              left_text
#> 1            tommorow is 2022 11 03            tommorow is
#> 2           I married on 2020-01-01           I married on
#> 3 why not going there on 2023/01/14 why not going there on
#> 4          2023 08 01 will be great          will be great
```

This will match dates by:

- `\\d{1,4}` = starting with either month (1-2 numeric characters), day (1-2 characters) or year (2-4 characters); followed by
- `\\D` = anything that's not a number, i.e. the separator; followed by
- `\\d{1,2}` = day or month (1-2 chars); followed by
- `\\D` again; ending with
- `\\d{1,4}` = day or year (1-2 or 2-4 chars)

The challenge is balancing sensitivity with specificity. This should not take out numbers which are clearly not dates, but might miss out:

- dates with no year
- dates with no separators
- dates with double spaces between parts

But hopefully should catch every *sensible* date in your text column!

### Further date detection examples:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  text = c(
    'tommorow is 2022 11 03',
    "I married on 2020-01-01",
    'why not going there on 2023/01/14',
    '2023 08 01 will be great',
    'A trickier example: January 05,2020',
    'or try Oct 2010',
    'dec 21/22 is another date'
  )
)


df |>
  mutate(left_text = str_remove(text, "\\d{1,4}\\D\\d{1,2}\\D\\d{1,4}") |> 
           str_remove(regex(paste0("(", paste(month.name, collapse = "|"),
                                   ")(\\D+\\d{1,2})?\\D+\\d{1,4}"),
                            ignore_case = TRUE)) |> 
           str_remove(regex(paste0("(", paste(month.abb, collapse = "|"),
                                   ")(\\D+\\d{1,2})?\\D+\\d{1,4}"),
                            ignore_case = TRUE)) |> 
           str_trim())

#>                                  text              left_text
#> 1              tommorow is 2022 11 03            tommorow is
#> 2             I married on 2020-01-01           I married on
#> 3   why not going there on 2023/01/14 why not going there on
#> 4            2023 08 01 will be great          will be great
#> 5 A trickier example: January 05,2020    A trickier example:
#> 6                     or try Oct 2010                 or try
#> 7           dec 21/22 is another date        is another date
```

### Final Edit - doing replace with temporary placeholders

The following code should work on a wide range of date formats. It works by replacing in a specific order so as not to accidentally chop out bits of some dates. Gluing together pre-made regex patterns to hopefully give a clearer idea as to what each bit is doing:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  text = c(
    'tommorow is 2022 11 03',
    "I married on 2020-01-01",
    'why not going there on 2023/01/14',
    '2023 08 01 will be great',
    'A trickier example: January 05,2020',
    'or try Oct 26th 2010',
    'dec 21/22 is another date',
    'today is 2023-01-29 & tomorrow is 2022 11 03 & 2022-12-01',
    'A trickier example: January 05,2020',
    '2020-01-01 I married on 2020-12-01',
    'Adding in 1st December 2018',
    'And perhaps Jul 4th 2023'
  )
)



r_year <- "\\d{2,4}"
r_day <- "\\d{1,2}(\\w{1,2})?"  # With or without "st" etc.
r_month_num <- "\\d{1,2}"
r_month_ab <- paste0("(", paste(month.abb, collapse = "|"), ")") 
r_month_full <- paste0("(", paste(month.name, collapse = "|"), ")") 
r_sep <- "[^\\w]+"  # The separators can be anything but letters

library(glue)

df |>
  mutate(
    text = 
      # Any numeric day/month/year
      str_replace_all(text,
                      glue("{r_day}{r_sep}{r_month_num}{r_sep}{r_year}"),
                      "REP_DATE") |> 
      # Any numeric month/day/year
      str_replace_all(glue("{r_month_num}{r_sep}{r_day}{r_sep}{r_year}"),
                      "REP_DATE") |> 
      # Any numeric year/month/day
      str_replace_all(glue("{r_year}{r_sep}{r_month_num}{r_sep}{r_day}"),
                      "REP_DATE") |> 
      # Any day[th]/monthname/year or monthname/day[th]/year
      str_replace_all(regex(paste0(
        glue("({r_day}{r_sep})?({r_month_full}|{r_month_ab})", 
             "{r_sep}({r_day}{r_sep})?{r_year}")
        ), ignore_case = TRUE),
                           "REP_DATE") |> 
      # And transform all placeholders to required date
      str_replace_all("REP_DATE", "25th October 2022")
    )
#>                                                                              text
#> 1                                                   tommorow is 25th October 2022
#> 2                                                  I married on 25th October 2022
#> 3                                        why not going there on 25th October 2022
#> 4                                                 25th October 2022 will be great
#> 5                                           A trickier example: 25th October 2022
#> 6                                                        or try 25th October 2022
#> 7                                               25th October 2022 is another date
#> 8  today is 25th October 2022 & tomorrow is 25th October 2022 & 25th October 2022
#> 9                                           A trickier example: 25th October 2022
#> 10                               25th October 2022 I married on 25th October 2022
#> 11                                                    Adding in 25th October 2022
#> 12                                                  And perhaps 25th October 2022
```

This should catch all the most common ways of writing dates, even with added "st"s "nd"s and "th"s after day number and irrespective of ordering of parts (apart from any format which puts "year" in the middle between "day" and "month", but that seems unlikely).

Comment: Thanks! it fixed those formats. I just saw dates in formats such as ```January 05,2020```, or ```oct 2010```, or ```dec 21/22```. Could you please advise on these three expressions? Much appreciated!

Comment: I've added some code which should detect any month name or 3-letter abbreviated name followed by any pattern of day/year. This is maybe starting to show the difficulty of what your regular expressions might have to look for - you may have to keep running them and adding more patterns as you see what's left!

Comment: Thanks Andy, it is working. Can you please advice how I can replace all these dates with one unique date, for example, ```oct 2022```? I think I should be able to use ```str_replace``` but not sure what else I should change to create ```oct 2022```

Comment: That might be trickier, but can be done with the same parts. You could replace the three calls to `str_remove` with `str_replace` and replace it with a placeholder such as `REP_DATE`, then `str_replace` all these with the desired dates. Or concatenate all three patterns above separated by `|` to replace in one go. Does this make sense? If there are more complicated things then probably best to try some solutions, close this thread and open a new one with new questions. comments aren't best place to go into more depth!

Comment: Thanks again! I could not figure out how to make the changes you mentioned. By any chances, can you please provide some code here? or as you suggested I can post another question but there is nothing more complicated left. Much appreciated!

Comment: I've added some code to try - see if that works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251443/discussion-between-alex-and-andy-baxter).

Comment: I noticed when the rows have two dates there is some bug appears: for these two ```today is 2023-01-29 & tomorrow is 2022 11 03 & 2022-12-01 A trickier example: January 05,2020``` I get ```today is 25th October 2022 & tomorrow is 2022 11 03 & 25th October 2022 A trickier example: REP_DATE ``` . in some rows, only one date is replaced and in some rows one date is replaced and the other date is replaced with the term```REP_DATE```

Comment: that should be solvable by switching all `str_replace` to `str_replace_all` - had opted for the simpler function but for multiple replacements the latter function should do what you need it to

Comment: Thanks again. It fixed some of them. But there are still two issues:  The first one is ```today is 2023-01-29 & tomorrow is 2022 11 03```  which changed to ```today is 25th October 2022 & tomorrow is 2022 11 03```. The Second one is ```2020-01-01 I married on 2020-12-01``` which changed wrongly  to ```25th October 2022 I 25th October 2022-12-0```.  First example could not replace two codes and second example removed the term ```married on``` wrongly and the second date is still there. Could you please advise? Much appreciated !

Comment: Have posted more details in chat!