# Replacing phone numbers in different formats in R

Tags: r, regex, text, data-cleaning

I am using a regex that is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number) to repleace any type of phone numbers with `aaaaaaaaaa`.
This a snapshot of my data :

```
df <- data.frame(
  text = c(
    'my number is (123)-416-567',
    "1 321 124 7889 is valid",
    'why not taking 987-012-6782',
    '120 967 3256 is correct',
    'call at 888 969 9919',
    'please text at 1 647 989 1213'
  )
)

df %>% select(text)

                           text
1    my number is (123)-416-567
2       1 321 124 7889 is valid
3   why not taking 987-012-6782
4       120 967 3256 is correct
5          call at 888 969 9919
6 please text at 1 647 989 1213
```

My code is

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    text = str_replace_all(text, '^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$', 'aaaaaaaaaa')
  )
```

and I get this error

```
Error: '\+' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'^(\+"
Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"
```

The outcome should be like

```
                           text
1           my number is aaaaaaaaaa
2           aaaaaaaaaa is valid
3           why not taking aaaaaaaaaa
4           aaaaaaaaaa is correct
5          call at aaaaaaaaaa
6          please text at  aaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Try ``'(?:\\+?\\d{1,2}\\s)?\\(?\\d{3}\\)?[\\s.-]\\d{3}[\\s.-]\\d{3,4}(?!\\d)'``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! it worked. can you please tell me what is wrong with what I wrote? it seems to be recommend by the members here. Much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - gsub replacing backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491986/r-gsub-replacing-backslashes) - _"The reason that you need four backslashes to represent one literal backslash is that `"\"` is an escape character in both R strings and for the regex engine to which you're ultimately passing your patterns. If you were talking directly to the regex engine, you'd use `"\\"` to indicate a literal backslash. But in order to get R to pass `"\\"` on to the regex engine, you need to type `"\\\\"`"_

Comment: However, fixing the slashes alone does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
str_replace_all(text, '(?:\\+?\\d{1,2}\\s)?\\(?\\d{3}\\)?[\\s.-]\\d{3}[\\s.-]\\d{3,4}(?!\\d)', 'aaaaaaaaaa')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nutsGS/2).

*Details*:

- `(?:\+?\d{1,2}\s)?` - an optional sequence of an optional `+` and then one or two digits and a whitespace
- `\(?` - an optional `(`
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `\)?` - an optional `)`
- `[\s.-]` - a `-`, `.` or whitespace
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `[\s.-]` - a `-`, `.` or whitespace
- `\d{3,4}` - three or four digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit alowed right after.

Notes:

- In a string literal, a backslash is defined with double `\` char
- `^` and `$` match start/end of string so in this case, it makes sense to remove the `^` anchor, and replace `$` with a right-digit boundary
- The last `\d{3}` did not match numbers where the last part contained four digits, so I replaced it with `\d{3,4}`.

Comment: Thanks! but can the last part contains three digits?

Comment: @Alex Your pattern implies that the last part can contain three digits. So, yes.

Comment: good catch, thanks alot! I think it is a data entry issue though. much appreciated again!

Comment: could you please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250599/removing-dates-in-any-format-form-a-text-column/75252092?noredirect=1#comment132798859_75252092) where I need to replace the dates? thank you again! much appreciated!